# How to read file into dictionary in Python specific filetype

Tags: python, dictionary, while-loop

Specifically, I have a text file with multiple lines arranged so that the key of each entry is the first line of a group, followed by its related values, followed by a newline before the next key.  I'm having a hard time using while loops to accomplish this with readline.

For example the first line may be a restaurant name, followed by several lines of customers who ate there, which I then need to write into the values of a dictionary under the key of a restaurant name.

I'm really unfamiliar with file reading so I'm afraid that what I have is not going to help at all really.

Something like this I guess, but it's not even to the point of semi-functional.

edit: Thanks for the response I should have clarified, each value item for a corresponding key is listed in subsequent lines after the key with the a blank line at the end of that list preceding the next key.  Also I am unfortunately compelled to use a readline approach here.

```
    restaurants = {}
    patrons = []

    line = file.readline()
    s = line.strip('\n')

    while s != ''
    restaurant = s
    line = file.readline
    patrons.append(s)
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include your attempt at a solution. Folks will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Also, could you provide an input and output examples?

Comment: Why are you "unfortunately compelled to use a readline approach here" as opposed to a `readlines()` approach?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming your text file looks like this

> mcdonalds bill bo bob

as per

> I have a text file with multiple lines arranged so that the key of
>   each entry is the first line of a group, followed by its related
>   values, followed by a newline

```
my_dict = {}

with open("rest.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        items = line.split()
        key, values = items[0], items[1:]
        my_dict[key] = values


print my_dict
```

which will produce

```
{'mcdonalds': ['bill', 'bo', 'bob']}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: revised according to the new problem specification.

```
with open("filename") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
restaurants = {}
current_key = None
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    if not line:
        current_key = None
    elif not current_key:
        current_key = line
        restaurants[current_key] = []
    else:
        restaurants[current_key].append(line)
```

If, as you say, you really truly cannot use `readlines()` here for some reason, just rewrite the `for` loop as a `while` loop that reads a line at a time until EOF.